# TypeError: pub is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I am exporting a `pub` function for rabbitmq

```
const pub = (queueName, data) => {
    // console.log(data)

    console.log(`   [amqp][sending] - ${queueName}`)
    // ch.assertQueue(queueName);
   ch.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(data));
}

module.exports = {
    pub,
    connect

}
```

while importing, i am using

```
const { pub } = require('../amqp')
```

while using it i am doing

```
try {
    pub(channel, JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(`  [AMQP][error] cant send to queue`)
  }
```

Seems all good but i am getting an error

```
TypeError: pub is not a function
```

When i put my cursor on `pub` i am able to see that its a function. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4E7f.png)

I am stuck with this for hours now and doesnt have a clue of how to proceed next.

Comment: just curious, would `import { pub } from '../amqp';` work?

Comment: unfortunately no